# Personal cache folder for a controller on CI4 (Code igniter 4)

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I see that theres a file on app/config/Cache.php where we can set the folder of the cache for the code igniter 4 framework.

As long as i do have many pages, the linux folder already has too many files.

I would like to set the $storePath variable to an specific folder. How could it be possible?

For instance, for the controller "A", when i set the cache ($this->cachePage(1000);) i also would set the folder for this controller.

Can anyone help me, please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should redefine CodeIgniter\Cache\Handlers\FileHandler::save method by adding your desired functionality

Comment: But in that way i would change for all website, isnt it? I just want to change the folder for an unique controller.

Comment: Add if(condition) parent::save(...args) ;

Comment: Alternatively, you can create your own customized FileHandler, and then while using that controller you can replace swap the default with your custom handler.